# What is the motivation for studying the normalized infinity Laplacian equation instead of the usual infinity Laplacian?

Tags: reference-request, proof-writing

I'd like to know why study the normalized infinity Laplacian equation $\Delta_\infty^N u = \langle D^2u \frac{Du}{|Du|},\frac{Du}{|Du|} \rangle$ instead of the usual infinity Laplacian
$\Delta_\infty^ u = \langle D^2u Du,Du \rangle$. What's the motivation?

Are the solutions solutions equivalent? More specifically, $\Delta_\infty^N u = 0 \equiv \Delta_\infty^ u =0.$ If I'm not wrong, if $u$ is a solution of the normalized infinity Laplacian equation, then $u$ is also a solution of the usual infinity Laplacian equation. On the other hand, the converse is not true in general. That is, $\Delta_\infty^u u = 0$ does not imply $\Delta_\infty^N u = 0$.

Could you give me a reference for this ask or a direct proof about the relation between these two concepts? Or a partial anwer to this questions.